# Github Action URL Checker failing, despite working link

Tags: github, url, github-actions

I am using the urlchecker action on my Github Repository to check for broken urls.
However, my link which seems to work is giving an error when being checked by the respective urlchecker Github action.

I have tried using [url-shortner](https://github.com/Agrover112/awesome-semantic-search/pull/48), but that doesn't work?
What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that one of the links didn't have a vaild SSL certificate and only had TSL certificates. Moereover, the Github URLChecker Action might be using Pythons `requests.get(url)` which seems to verify for SSL by default as mentioned [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification), therefore a compeletely working link without an SSL(maybe having a TLS) might fail the URL Check.
(This is speculation from my side as to how the url checker action works but the most likely scenario in this [case](https://github.com/urlstechie/urlchecker-python) )